# Video streaming in Qt

Tags: c++, multithreading, qt

I am trying to display more than one video in Qt (in one window) but I get data for each video from a unique socket in a thread as I know we cant access qt widget from another thread so I have to signal to the main thread that data is ready but this is a burden on the main thread, you can imagine 10 or more threads signaling to the main thread whenever a frame arrives, am I right to think this way if so, can you suggest a different approach ?

I have googled a lot and read about threading in Qt but I need someone to clear my doubts thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Don't worry, signaling alone will not overburden the main thread's event loop, even if queued connections are significantly slower than direct connections, you can still have tens, possibly even hundreds per seconds without running into trouble.

Just make sure you are not using the connections to transfer the actual data. As your threads are in a single process, they share the same addressing space, so you can avoid slow data transfers altogether.

Now whether your main thread has enough processing power to display 10 video widgets is a whole different story.

Comment: there is no data transfer but as you know i will be updating all the labels in the main thread, this wont be a lot of work to the main thread?

Comment: I don't think so. If so, you could try queuing the updates and executing them in a single swoop. But don't worry about performance problems before you know you have them, premature optimizations are usually a waste of time and needlessly increase complexity and chances of bugs.

Comment: @ddriver +1 - this is a well documented concept, but often overlooked (I have made this mistake enough!). Get something working first and worry about making your life complicated later. If you are still worried that you are too close to the edge later, you can always profile your program and see where you are losing time - or how much you have to spare : )

Comment: when signaling to a slot in the main window wouldn't this slot get executed in the the thread that emitted the signal by default or i am just missing something @ddriver

Comment: yeah you are right @code_fodder but sometimes thinking your plan will work or not and precautions saves you alot of trouble switching to a another plan if the first one didn't work

Comment: @mohammed if you signal across threads then slot is executed in the receiving thread - it is basically like a message box. IFF you pick the exactly correct "precautions" up front, it may save time. The problem is once you add complexity trying to optimise you actually end up with a more rigid system which is harder to re-factor later. If you are doing all your design up front right with a well define system you may get away with it. Keeping it simple will keep flexibility high and refactoring costs low - i.e. if you are working in a more agile approach then you don't know your final design...

Comment: @code_fodder check qt documentation, this is really confusing http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qt.html#ConnectionType-enum

Comment: Qt::directConnection "The slot is invoked immediately when the signal is emitted. The slot is executed in the signaling thread"

Comment: @mohammed - are you using directconnection across threads? The default is Qt::QueuedConnection. In my humble opinion, I think its very unsafe (both thread-unsafe and logically unsafe) to use direct connections across threads. It totally breaks rules of encapsulation, I am very surprised that Qt even allows this behaviour. I can't think of a reason to ever to do this (I welcome examples) that you can't accomplish with queued connection AND that keeps your code safe/encapsulated. It is like punching a hole through the wall smash-and-grab style, may as well not bother with threads :o - IMHO

Comment: @mohammed (ran outta space) the other issue is that direct connection (DC) runs immediately therefore "interrupting" anything in the receiving thread queue (even though it runs in sender thread - as you say), this can be make your design somewhat un-deterministic. I.e. you don't really know at what point your DC will run, whereas in a queue order is guaranteed - therefore easier to design and debug and less chance to hit a dead lock etc...  Again, I will go back to "keep it simple" use queued connection which acts more like standard message queues and avoid a lot of headaches and pain : )

Comment: @code_fodder i got your point, it might be a bad idea, i will work with queued connection type, i was just afraid that 20+ threads sending 60 FPS each (1200+ FPS ovarall ) will be a burden on the the main thread (no data transfer involved) so i was basically hoping to do the work in the socket threads instead but as you and ddriver said i should try it first then worry if there is a problem, thank you very much i will post again if there is any problem

Comment: @code_fodder BTW is there any other safe way to make the socket threads do the work instead

Comment: @mohammed Its difficult to say without seeing your code, but what I can say is that all widgets and GUI elements in Qt need to be in the Gui thread. However that does not mean that your video qtWidget can't farm off heavy processing to another thread (this is a common practise). I don't know the performance, but IIRC QMediaPlayer already runs the video processing in its own thread/threads in the background - meaning that you don't need to worry about splitting the work up yourself. I would ask if your PC can run 20 media players at once? - your bottle neck may be the PC itself.

Comment: @code_fodder yeah i got what you mean and if Qt does it's own thread to manage heavy work there is no need for me to intervene :), i will make sure of that and continue writting code now for me enough thinking and let's get to work, thank you very much you have been of great help :)

Comment: @mohammed ah, no problem dude, a collaborative effort : )